# Nunit complaining about Nhibernate.config file missing?

Tags: nhibernate

I have a MVC project where I have a Class Library setup as my Test project.  However, when using NUnit to run my tests, it is complaining about not finding the Nhibernate.config (which is in my Web project bin.

The exact error:

```
<solutionName>.UnitTests.CatelogEditing.Can_View_All_Products_On_Admin_Product_List:
System.TypeInitializationException : The type initializer for '<solutionName>.Domain.Infrastructure.BootStrapper' threw an exception.
  ----> NHibernate.Cfg.HibernateConfigException : An exception occurred during configuration of persistence layer.
  ----> System.IO.FileNotFoundException : Could not find file '<myrootpath>.UnitTests\bin\Debug\nhibernate.config'.
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add config file into your tests project because it doesn't know about your web project and doesn't see NH config file.

Comment: I had copied it over, but  didn't realize that the properties would default back.  So Build action and copy settings were not in place.

Comment: Any idea once I got past that error, Unit wants to complain that it can't find "Named Connection String" and lists my computer name.  I am using "cfg.SetProperty(NHibernate.Cfg.Environment.ConnectionStringName, System.Environment.MachineName);"  in my CreateSessionFactory method, and have added attribute "name = <mycomputername>" to my Web.config.

Answer (score 4):

Have you set the following properties of the config file:

**Build Action: Content**

**Copy to Output Directory: Copy Always**

To ensure that it is copied to the bin directory?